# MySQL check for active transaction inside trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, sqltransaction

I want a trigger on a table to fail if a transaction isn't active. I've tried to used the `autocommit` variable, but it apparently isn't affected by `START TRANSACTION` so it will in my case always be `1` anyway. I want to do something like:

```
IF ![transaction check] THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Transaction must be active';
END IF;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for table locks with `SHOW PROCESSLIST`